# Get the position of complex vector in complex matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing, complex-numbers

I need to get the  position of vector (which is complex) in a complex matrix.

For example I have the matrix `X` as below:

```
X = [ -0.7071 + 0.7071, 0.00 + 0.00i, 0.00 + 0.00i, 0.00 + 0.00i;
       0.00 + 0.00i, -0.7071 + -0.7071, 0.00 + 0.00i, 0.00 + 0.00i;
       0.00 + 0.00i, 0.00 + 0.00i, -0.7071 + 0.7071, 0.00 + 0.00i; 
      -0.7071 + 0.7071, -0.7071 + 0.7071, 0.00 + 0.00i, 0.00 + 0.00i; 
      -0.7071 + 0.7071, 0.00 + 0.00i, -0.7071 + 0.7071; 0.00 + 0.00i ];
```

And I have a complex vector

```
Y = [ 0.00 + 0.00i, 0.00 + 0.00i, -0.7071 + 0.7071, 0.00 + 0.00i ];
```

So, what I need is that to get the index of `Y` in the matrix `X`. In my example, it's 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ismember` function can be used to determine wheter a vector is a row in a matrix:

```
[~,indx] = ismember(X', Y', 'row')
```

`indx` will be a vector which says if `Y'` is in that row of `X'` (columns when talking about `Y` and `X`). To know the index you want, you just have to do:

```
solution = find(indx == 1)
```

That will return all the columns that `Y` appears `X`.

Comment: You cannot do equality tests with floating-point numbers, this is a disaster waiting to happen. Instead, use `ismembertol`, which does the comparison with a tolerance.